# How to get local business names using only lat/long (swift4, MKMapView)?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I've been spending hours trying to work out how to get the local business names when I touch on a business icon on MKMapView, but it looks to me like Apple doens't want you to get this information.

For example I'm trying to get the Placemark of this Kroger located at this lat/long:

```
Kroger, 536 Centennial Blvd, Richardson, TX  75081, United States 
<+32.93644619,-96.72057518>
```

Using reverse geolocation of this EXACT location i get the placemark.name of the street set to "Centennial Blvd", and not "Kroger" like i expect.

But if I use a MKLocalSearchRequest() with the naturalLanguageQuery = "Kroger", I get back a list of placemarks with this Kroger in it (plus 9 others), but the placemark name is set correctly to "Kroger".

I need my tap gesture to be able to look up the business name without using any naturalLanguageQuery text. but it doesn't seem to be doable.  How do i do this?

Here are the two code blocks.

1) This code returns "Centennial Blvd"

```
let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
let kroger = CLLocation(latitude: +32.93644619, longitude: -96.72057518)

geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(kroger, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

    // Place details
    var placeMark: CLPlacemark!
    placeMark = placemarks?[0]
    //print(placeMark.addressDictionary)

    // Location name
    if let locationName = placeMark.name {
        print("locationName: \(locationName)")
    }
})
```

2) While this code, returns "Kroger" @ <+32.93644619,-96.72057518>

```
let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Kroger"
let kroger2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: +32.93644619, longitude: -96.72057518)
let span = self.mapView.region.span
request.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: kroger2, span: span)

let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
search.start { response, error in
    guard let response = response else {
        print("There was an error searching for: \(request.naturalLanguageQuery) error: \(error)")
        return
    }
    print("There are \(response.mapItems.count)")
    for item in response.mapItems {
        print("Item Placemark Name: \(item.placemark.name!)")
    }
}
```

Edit: I've read that google has APIs that can help here, but i don't want to use any other 3rd party APIs for this, i need to do this using MapKit/CoreLocation.

Comment: Have you checked the other placemarks returned?

Comment: Well, it returns a single place mark in that case... It seems that scenario is not really something Apple had in mind. One thing you could try is to use a `MKLocalSearchCompleter` and try all letters as query fragments, and retrieve the associated results for each. Possibly stopping as soon as you have a hit that has the right coordinates. But that may be a bit outside what Apple wants to accept... But what's really your use case?

Comment: I want to replicate something similar to Apple Maps, when you tap on the place icon it pops up a menu..

Comment: I understand what you are saying about the limitations of reverse geo-coding.  I don't understand what is happening with your tap gesture. If you are tapping "a business icon" on the map, why do you only have the lat/long? Why do you need to look anything up if its already on the map?

Comment: Because i need to use the business name in my code. The business name and icon shows on the map, but its no accessible.